# Why does my change of variable not work?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus

I have an integral of the form $I=\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \int_{R(u_2,u_3)}f(u_1)\mathrm{d}u_1\mathrm{d}u_2 \mathrm{d}u_3$ where I have the region $R(u_2,u_3)=\{u_1: 0\leq |\frac{1}{-2}(u_1-3u_2N-5u_3N)| \leq N\}$. Here, $N$ is a positive constant and we can make it as large as we like.

As $N$ can be very large, we can rewrite the condition for $R(u_2,u_3)$ as $0\leq (3u_2N+5u_3N-u_1)\leq 2N$. Then $u_1$ can range from $8-2N$ to $8$ as $u_2,u_3\in [0,1]$.
My question is if can make a change of variables as $I=\int_8^{8-2N} \int_{S(u_1)} f(u_1) \mathrm{d}u_2 \mathrm{d}u_3 \mathrm{d}u_1$, where $S(u_1)=\{(u_2,u_3)\in [0,1]^2| 0\leq |\frac{1}{-2}(u_1-3u_2N-5u_3N)|\leq N\}$? If not, what's the correct way to exchange the order of integration? Thank you for your help!

Comment: $0\leq |\frac{1}{-2}(u_1-3u_2N-5u_3N)| \leq N$ is equivalent to $-2N\leq (3u_2N+5u_3N-u_1)\leq 2N$, rather than $0\leq (3u_2N+5u_3N-u_1)\leq 2N$.

Comment: Oh no! That was careless of me. Thanks a lot!